# What is the highest a helicopter can fly?

Tags: aerodynamics, altitude

What is the highest theoretical and current flight a helicopter can achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This (and more) is quite easily answered by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicopter#World_records)

Highest altitude without payload
12,442 m (40,820 ft)
Aerospatiale Lama

Highest level flight altitude
11,010 m (36,120 ft)
Sikorsky CH-54 Tarhe

Altitude with 40-tonne payload
2,255 m (7,398 ft)
Mil V-12

Visit the linked Wikipedia article for more records and sources.